# OpenCV library package was not found

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to run some OpenCV examples on an MDP (mobile development platform) based on the Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 805 Processor. The platform has no Google Play and it cannot be installed.

I have installed the correct OpenCV manager and the OpenCV binary pack. After trying to run a sample OpenCV app (e.g. the 15 puzzle) I get the following message:

"OpenCV library package was not found! Try to install it?"

Of course, I cannot install it, since there is no Google Play Store. How can I get the OpenCV library package onto the device and am I wrong to think that the OpenCV binary pack is exactly that?

Comment: but its working on 4.4? Not working from 5.0 and above.

Comment: create a jniLibs folder under your main folder(same location as your java folder)

just copy the corresponding OpenCV native libs(there should be seven folders, mips, x86 etc..copy the ones you need, depends on what cpu your app will be running on) from /sdk/native/libs/ to your project directory to folder jniLibs

then in your activity